# how to insert and delete on language c with methods and function?

Tags: c, arrays

Implement a simple linked list that manages non-negative integers. The list should include
the following functions:
-int insertElement(int value): Adds a value to the list if it does not already exist.
If successful, the function returns the inserted value, otherwise the value -1.

-int removeElement(void): Removes the oldest value from the list and returns it. If it’s not
available in the
List, -1 will be returned.

-Do not implement any list functionality in the main () function. However, you can use the
main () function to test your implementation.
-Attempting to add a negative number to the list should be prevented and counted as an
error.
-If an error occurs while executing a function (e.g. malloc (3)), there are no error messages
to output {but the error must be handled appropriately according to the task.
-Running the Program on a terminal after translating it with the gcc –o command should give
it the following output:
insert 47: 47
insert 11: 11
insert 23: 23
insert 11: -1
remove: 47
remove: 11

Program

````
#include <stdlib.h>
// TODO: structs, global variables, etc.

int insertElement(int value) {
// TODO: implement me!
return -1;
}

int removeElement(void) {
// TODO: implement me!
return -1;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
printf("insert 47: %d\n", insertElement(47));
printf("insert 11: %d\n", insertElement(11));
printf("insert 23: %d\n", insertElement(23));
printf("insert 11: %d\n", insertElement(11));

printf("remove: %d\n", removeElement());
printf("remove: %d\n", removeElement());

// TODO: add more tests
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

**My Programme** 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void insert(int t[] , int val , int n ){

    int i ;
    int indice = -1 ; 

    for( i = 0 ;i< n ;i++){
        if(t[i]== n){
            indice = i ;
            break; 
        }
    }   
    if( indice ==-1){
        t[n+1] = val ;
    }
    for(i = 0 ;i < n ;i++){
        printf("%d",t[i]);
    }


}
int main (){
    int t[100];
    int val;
    int i , n;


    printf("donner nomber du tab ");
    scanf("%D",&n);

    for(i =0 ; i<n ;i++){
        printf("Remplit la case n : %d",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&t[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0 ;i < n ; i++){
        printf("%d",t[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n\n Donner la valeur que vous voulez ajouter ");
    scanf("%d",&val);
//  ins = insert(T ,val ,n);

    printf("votre nouveau tableau est : %0.2f",insert(t[] , val, n));
    return 0;

    // 
}
    ```
````

Comment: You need to focus your question for us to be able to help you. If you want help with a homework assignment, I recommend reading this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions . If you want the general concept of how to implement a list in C, it's not an array but a group of structs that point to each other - check this tutorial: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/linked-list/singly-linked-list/tutorial/ .

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is to add a singly linked list, but you have implemented an array. You should check on internet on how to implement linked list, basically you create a struct with values needed to be stored and a pointer of struct type, then in the function should dynamically allocate memory to create these struct variables and link them to previously created  or head to create a linked list

```
struct list
{
    //data needed to be inserted
    struct list *pointer;
};
```

I'm not writing entire create element and remove element functions for you, but it should go something like this.
Create element:

```
   struct list *p=malloc( sizeof(struct list));

    //Adding values needed

   //If head is NULL
   head=p;
   //else
  PreviouslyCreatedListPointer --> pointer= p;

  //After all edge case checking

  p--> pointer=NULL;
```

Figure out delete on your own from this:

```
//checking and finding node to be deleted

previousnode--> pointer = nextnode;
```

And that's it.

And for next time, don't expect to post a question on a forum and someone to make the program for you. You've got to learn it yourself.